# MySQL: Sum the total number of unique ids

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database, I wish to output the total number of books with reviews after a certain date:

```
> SELECT book_id, AVG(score)
  FROM review
  WHERE review.date > "2012-07-11"
  GROUP BY review.book_id ;
+---------+------------+
| book_id | AVG(score) |
+---------+------------+
| 345335  | 3.5        |
| 974147  | 3          |
| 723923  | 4          |
| 281192  | 3          |
| 384423  | 3.5        |
| 123122  | 3.5        |
| 112859  | 3          |
| 234892  | 5          |
+---------+------------+
```

Now, I would like to know the "total number" of books which meet this condition. That is, I need a total sum of the `book_id`.

However, I am not sure how to do this. How do you `SELECT` the `SUM(book_id)`?

Comment: Don't you mean you want the count, rather than the sum? E.g. how many of each there are, rather than the values of the IDs added together?

Comment: @Bridge Yes, how many of each there are. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm pretty sure you don't want the `SUM` because that would be *3,179,893*. `SUM` means adding up all the values and totaling them.

Instead you probably want the `COUNT` of `DISTINCT` ids that match your criteria. `COUNT`ing means "how many rows" or using your words the "total number" of entities. And `DISTINCT` is the keyword which only looks at unique values.

So in SQL, this would be:

```
select count(distinct book_id)
from review
where review.date > '2012-07-11'
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment so I can improve my answer?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe using `COUNT()` is what you want:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html